# re.split() gives empty elements in list

Tags: python, regex

please help with this case:

```
m = re.split('([A-Z][a-z]+)', 'PeopleRobots')
print (m)
```

Result:

```
['', 'People', '', 'Robots', '']
```

Why does the list have empty elements?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [re.split documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

> If there are capturing groups in the separator and it matches **at the
>   start of the string**, the result will start with an empty string. The
>   same holds for **the end of the string**:

If you want to get `People` and `Robots`, use [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+)', 'PeopleRobots')
['People', 'Robots']
```

You can omit grouping:

```
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]+', 'PeopleRobots')
['People', 'Robots']
```

Comment: You don't even need the brackets, if capturing is not needed.

Comment: @mavili, I mentioned that. Thank you.

Comment: Also, empty strings are produced between consecutive matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Could you give me example string that produce empty strings?

Comment: @falsetru This is related to `re.split` producing empty items in the resulting list. As with `print(re.split('(\W*)', 'a---b'))` resulting in `['', '', 'a', '---', '', '', 'b', '', '']`, [here is a demo](https://ideone.com/DO1xAQ).