# add space between number and string python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I want to add space between number and text

Example string: `ABC24.00XYZ58.28PQR`

output: `ABC 24.00 XYZ 58.28 PQR`

Please let me know the answers.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) back-referencing the captured group to add the spaces:

```
s = 'ABC24.00XYZ58.28PQR'

 re.sub('(\d+(\.\d+)?)', r' \1 ', s).strip()
# 'ABC 24.00 XYZ 58.28 PQR'
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XlZaHe/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split` to separate the input string into a list of tokens. Then join all those tokens by a space.

```py
import re

s = "ABC24.00XYZ58.28PQR"
split = [c for c in re.split(r'([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)', s) if c]
result = " ".join(split)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
ABC 24.00 XYZ 58.28 PQR
```

The regex `r'([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)'` should be fairly robust and detect floats of the type `-12`, `+5.0` as well.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no more requirements,you could use regex:

```
import re

s = "ABC24.00XYZ58.28PQR"
s = re.sub("[A-Za-z]+",lambda group:" "+group[0]+" ",s)
print(s.strip())
```

Comment: You can back-reference the captured groups, as `\1`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61184274/9698684)

Answer (score -2):

Use Regex refer:
[python regex add space whenever a number is adjacent to a non-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681439/python-regex-add-space-whenever-a-number-is-adjacent-to-a-non-number)

Comment: It seems the question is asking about conversion, rather than just creation of the string.

Comment: We also can refer the similar thread link provided for the solution using regex